# Compiling iOS Apps from multiple macs

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have a free developer account. With it, I compile two or three Apps on my own iPhone.
I was used to compile the Applications regularly when the certificate expired.

Now, I'm using more my laptop, so I compile sometimes the Apps from it, and sometimes from the iMac. I think now having another problem, and I have to recompile the applications more frequently. After laucnching the App I have sometimes the message

> Unable to verify App
>
> An Internet connection is required to verify trust of the developer "xxx". This App will not be available until verified

I think that the problem is that I have two apps on the iPhone, for the same developer account, but compiled with thwo different Macs. I don't know why, but Apple seems to consider the account for a machine, not for a developer...

I tried to resolve the problem by using the exact same certificate on the two machines (synchronise the folder ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles with Syncthing), but it didn't help.

I assume I can create another developer account and use one account for just one application, but it seems ridiculous...

Is this a way to avoid this message?

Comment: The simplest way is to pay the $99

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you mean that, with a paid developer account, you can compile Apps with different Macs and never have  this message?

Comment: with a paid account profile verification only happens every 30 days or so. You can also create unlimited app provisioning profiles and apps run longer without needing to be recompiled